# how can I reconnect my application at every opening to the same bluetooth low energy device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an Android app. At the start this app show to the user a list of bluetooth devices and when he chooses one of they  opens an other activity.

My goal is : after some day  when the user will reopen the app the app will have to remember the ble device and it have to try to reconnect to it.

For now I have obtained my goal in this way :

- I memorize in preference the mac address of the chosen device
- When the user reopen the app the app do a hidden scan and try to reconnect to a device with a same MAC address.
- for retrieve the mac address I use the function getAddress() (when I try to connect to the android peripheral this function gives me
  some problem, because the  the device changes his MAC address at each
  starts :/)

There is a best way to obtain the same thing ?

Off topic : The function  onScanResult in the ScanResult some time return to me null device, is it normal ?
I have uses startLeScan(UUID[] serviceUuids, BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback callback) and after lollipop I use the new version of the startLeScan with Scanfilter. Can it be the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For privacy reasongs the mac address keeps on changing-refer below snippet from the ble specs:

> 5.4.5 Privacy Feature
>
> Bluetooth LE supports a feature that reduces the ability to track a LE device over a period of time by changing the
>   Bluetooth device address on a frequent basis. The privacy feature is
>   not used in the GAP discovery mode and procedures but it is used, when
>   supported, during connection mode and connection procedures. In order
>   for a device using the privacy feature to reconnect to known devices,
>   the device address, referred to as the private address, must be
>   resolvable by the other device.
>
> The private address is generated using
>   the device’s resolving identity key (IRK) exchanged during the bonding
>   procedure.

So the ideal way is to use the IRK to gerate the actual address of the device.However I didnt find any API to do it.

Currently,the work around- which I am using in mny app- to re-connect to the device,

1. loop through all the available device.
2. get the serial no-if the serial no matches the already stored number
   then keep the connection else disconnect.
3. Repeat step 2 for all the devices.

   This work around will only work if the device exposes serial number through some service.

You can also try setting the *autoconnect* flag to true when you call  [connectGatt (Context context, boolean autoConnect, BluetoothGattCallback callback)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#connectGatt%28android.content.Context,%20boolean,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback%29)

From the docs:

> public BluetoothGatt connectGatt (Context context, boolean autoConnect, 
>   BluetoothGattCallback callback) Added in API level 18
>
> Connect to GATT Server hosted by this device. Caller acts as GATT
>   client. The callback is used to deliver results to Caller, such as
>   connection status as well as any further GATT client operations. The
>   method returns a BluetoothGatt instance. You can use BluetoothGatt to
>   conduct GATT client operations. Parameters
>
> autoConnect   Whether to
>   directly connect to the remote device (false) or to automatically
>   connect as soon as the remote device becomes available (true).
>
> callback  GATT callback handler that will receive asynchronous
>   callbacks. Throws IllegalArgumentException    if callback is null